# Nested Forms: How to get a "this"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I use nested forms and would like to get some kind of "this" in it:

The View looks like this:

```
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :user_id %><br />
        <%= f.number_field :user_id %>
      </div>
      <% f.fields_for :assignments do |builder| %>
        <%= builder.label :count %>
        <%= builder.text_field :count %>
        <%= @a.fetch(this.id) %>
      <% end %>
```

The @a is an array with the caption of the assignment. So how can I access the current assignment? Or would this code only display a form for one assignment?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via `#object` applied to your builder:

```
builder.object.id
```